# Request for help to speed up batch program for 17,000 TXT files

Tags: regex, batch

I have over 17,000 pages that have been scanned (for a local history archive) which I have OCRed using Tesseract to individual TXT files. I want to be able to search/locate every page containing a search word of more than 3, lower case letters. So for each TXT file I need to:

- Delete all rubbish from the OCR text i.e. non-alphanumeric characters:
  `jrepl "[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]" "" /x /f %%G /O -`
- Remove 1, 2 and 3 letter words: `jrepl "\b\w{1,3}\b" "" /x /f %%G /O -`
- Change all characters to lower case: `jrepl "(\w)" "$1.toLowerCase()" /i /j /x /f %%G /O -`
- To be able to sort the remaining words they need to be on separate new lines: `jrepl "\s" "\n" /x /f %%G /O -`
- Finally sort all unique words into alphabetic order and create the modified TXT file: `sort /UNIQUE %%G /O %%G`

I have a batch file that does the above using JREPL but it is very slow. It has been running for over 100 HOURS and I'm not even half way. Any suggestions so as to speed up the processing? I am running Windows 10.

This is the Batch file I am running:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%G in (*.txt) do (
set old=%%G
echo !old!
@echo on

rem remove non-alphanumeric
call jrepl "[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]" "" /x /f %%G /O -

rem remove 1, 2 and 3 letter words
call jrepl "\b\w{1,3}\b" "" /x /f %%G /O -

rem all to lowercase
call jrepl "(\w)" "$1.toLowerCase()" /i /j /x /f %%G /O -

rem replace spaces with new lines
call jrepl "\s" "\n" /x /f %%G /O -

rem reduce to unique words
sort /UNIQUE %%G /O %%G

)
pause
```

Comment: in my test the conversion to lowercase is done by sort automaticly and you could try to replace non-alphanumeric, <=3 letter words and spaces to \n in one go `([^a-zA-Z0-9]|\s|\b\w{1,3}\b)+`

Comment: Correction: only the uniqueness is  case independent, you get one version picked out.